# How can i click on a nested anchor href tag using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my html code:

```
<a href="guestProfile.do?reloadGuest=true&amp;gmp=42017073774&amp;resConf=400007053&amp;roomSeq=1&amp;rrsId=1&amp;propId=712" target="sgr" <a="" name="Y">YIKKU, TFYTUR</a>
```

I want to click on the link name YIKKU TFYTUR, i have tried the following but nothing worked-

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("YIKKU, TFYTUR")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='Y']")).click();
```

can anyone please help me??

Comment: I think your css query should be a[name='Y']

Comment: No, it is <a="" name="Y"> and i tried the following code but it is not working.

Comment: Not sure but try driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[target='sgr']")).click();

Comment: I tried this, but still the link is not identified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution to these kind of Href tags are find the nearest "id" element, in my case was this-

```
<table id="resSearchResultsTBL">
```

then find this element using css selector:

```
WebElement guest = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table[id='resSearchResultsTBL']"));
```

and then find again in this element a sub element of "a href" tag:

```
guest.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='guestProfile.do']")).click();
```

This worked perfectly for me.:)

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@name=\"Y\"]"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(link));
link.click();
```

or

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@target=\"sgr\"]"));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(link));
link.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, but however Xpath is not working in my html code.I solved the issue by using css selector, below is how i did it.